# twitter bootstrap jquery foreground div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

hy, i have this code `[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/j753q/` but the problem is when the mouse hover on the first div the second div's position changes. i have tried many solutions but nothing really works fine. 
For example this site is what i want to do:
http://www.scarpescarpestore.com/donna.html

i'm using twitterbootstrap and jquery with responsive layout: row-fluid system

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use absolute positioning in order to place the items that should show on hover on top of the item (and without pushing the others).  You can check out the source at the link you posted to see how they do this, more or less.